# Why cant I enable Opengl with XFCE and Plasma and radeon driver?

Tags: xfce, amd-graphics, opengl

I can enable Opengl in KDE Compositor Settings, but it keeps falling back to Xrender. Why is that?

Glxinfo gives me this:

```
glxinfo | grep direct direct rendering: Yes 

glxinfo | grep -i opengl  
OpenGL vendor string: X.Org R300 Project  
OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on ATI RV515  
OpenGL version string: 2.1 Mesa 10.5.2  
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.20  
OpenGL extensions:  
OpenGL ES profile version string:  
OpenGL ES 2.0 Mesa 10.5.2  
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string:  
OpenGL ES GLSL ES 1.0.16  
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because KDE (plasma) falls back to Xrender if

- OpenGl fails because of an error or
- it does not enable OpenGl because it detects that the graphics card or the graphics driver is not "safe" to run with OpenGl.

In `~/home/<user>/.kde/share/config/kwinrc` the use of OpenGl can be forced by adding the following lines to the `compositing-section`:

```
UnredirectFullscreen=false
XRenderSmoothScale=false
```

If KDE runs fine then everything is ok, if KDE was right with fallback one will notice crashes of plasma.